# Delete tables with foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I installed a wordpress plugin and I want to delete it now to remove all data. So I went to phpmyadmin to remove all data but unfortunately I could delete only 2 tables (5 in total). When I delete this table as example I get this error.

```
#1451 - Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`f1zone_news`.`wp_msr_driver_races_for`, CONSTRAINT `wp_msr_driver_races_for_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`engine_id`) REFERENCES `wp_msr_engine` (`id_engine`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

What can I do to delete all the tables?

Thank you!

Comment: most probably you can just run your delete command again. in the first run tables that are referenced in foreign keys of other tables will not get deleted, but those that are not (and may contain those forein keys) will, if you run the command again the next "layer" of tables will get deleted, of course you can circumvent this in general by just deleting in the right order ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
First you have to delete record from child table 
then you can update or delete record from parent table.
```

Comment: Thank you but I'm very new to this. What do I have to do first exactly?

Comment: If you want to update or delete primary key in parent table then you must delete child record containing as foreign key.

Comment: I want to delete all 5 tables. But what is the child record? and how do I find it?

Comment: Can you give me either tbl_name or tbl_schema?

Comment: I'm so sorry. I only know how to work with wordpress. But because I couldn't get this plugin to delete it entirely I decided to delete it from the database. What is tbl_name?

Here's a screenshot of the table I want to delete: http://i.imgur.com/Rrf9C0E.png

Comment: Hello please any update on this? as I really should delete it before tomorrow :(